What happens when a memory adress is casted like this?
I wanted to look at the byte-representation of different objects in memory and found this function to do it:
template <typename T>
void print_bytes(const T& input, std::ostream& os = std::cout)
{
  const unsigned char* p = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&input);
  os << std::hex << std::showbase;
  os << "[";
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<sizeof(T); ++i)
    os << static_cast<int>(*(p++)) << " ";
  os << "]" << std::endl;;
}

At this stack overflow post

What I am curious about is why the address of input is casted in: const unsigned char* p = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&input);?

Initially I thought casting like this would somehow alter the memory address since different types are different sizes and therefore need a different amount of bytes to be represented. So I wrote the following:
int x = 4328;
auto* p0 = &x;
auto* p1 = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(p0);
printf("%p\n", p0);
printf("%p\n", p1);

Output:
0x7ffdd1bff604
0x7ffdd1bff604

So they are not altered. So whats really happening here?

What does the size of the object have to do with its address?

It may alter the address, but not because of the size.

The cast only changes the way you look at the object, not where it resides in memory (It might change the address, but only in cases of multiple inheritance, which is a rather advanced issue).

@yurikilochek I thought each byte of an object is assigned a address in memory. If a two objects have different sizes, one object would require a "larger" address than the other. But I am probably wrong if you think this is a stupid question :)

@user3612 the address of the object, is actually the address of the first byte that represents the object in memory (that's a simplication but it's close enough for the current context). So the size is not relevant here.

@wohlstad Ahh, so the pointer address is really just the address of the first byte? So to get the full address you would have to go through the address of every byte representing the object?

@user3612 no, that is not accurate. The address of an object is simply "where it begins" in memory (roughly speaking). There are no multiple addresses (again up to the issue of multiple inheritance which is not relevant here). However there could be multiple bytes representing the object, starting at that address.

Ok, thank you. But is it correct that "where it begins" is the address of the first byte?  And a pointer can be incremented to point to the address of the next byte and so on.

@user3612 yes. But be aware that incrementing a pointer depends on the pointer type. If you increment a pointer to type T (i.e. the pointer is of type T*), the address will be incremented by sizeof(T). So for the purpose of incrementing a pointer, a cast to a different one does make a difference. To traverse all bytes you should therefore use  an unsigned char * or similar (like uint8_t*). To learn more about incrementing pointers you can search for "C++ pointer arithmetics".

Change printf("%p\n", p0); to printf("%p %zu\n", p0, sizeof *p0);, and for the other one as well.

Ignoring byte order and stuff ("endianess"), let's assume you have a 4-byte integer with value 0x12345678 stored in memory like this:
address 2200 -> 0x12
address 2201 -> 0x34
address 2202 -> 0x56
address 2203 -> 0x78

int32_t test=0x12345678;     // assume it's stored like above
int32_t* p=&test;            // "p" now has the value "2200"
assert(*p==0x12345678);      // read value through pointer

Now, if you cast the pointer to char*, it will still have the value:
unsigned char* q=reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(p);       // "q" also has "2200"
assert((void*)p==(void*)q);

It's the same pointer, you're just telling the compiler it points to something different. This is why reinterpret_cast is rarely used -- it's a very dangerous thing without much of a real use case.
However, since "char" is just one byte, dereferencing q gives a different value:
assert(*q==0x12);       // just one byte at the pointer location
assert(q[0]==0x12);
assert(q[1]==0x34);     // we know it's 4 bytes, so we can safely read the others
assert(q[2]==0x56);
assert(q[3]==0x78);

As a side note, while the above is merely meant to be a basic overview, most computer systems that you'll encounter will store that integer differently:
address 2200 -> 0x78
address 2201 -> 0x56
address 2202 -> 0x34
address 2203 -> 0x12

It just looks backwards, so I've chosen the "big endian" format for my explanation, while stuff tends to run "little endian" these days.

In the line: 'assert((void*)p==(void*)q);' Are you casting the pointers to void because the pointers has to point to the same object types to be comparable?

Ok, I think I understood your explanation: The reason the pointer to unsigned char* is that it makes the dereferncing operator only return a single byte at a time as opposed to all the bytes (which is the entire object) at one time? Since the chars are unsigned its corresponding integer range is [0, 255] which is the same range as a 8-bit byte. So by casting to int and using the hex output manipulator you can display all the bytes in hex format?

The void*, yes, I just wanted them to be compatible. And yes on the other stuff, I think. Note that I generally prefer using uint8_t when dealing with "bytes", but since your code used unsigned char, I stuck with that. If at all possible, I use char only when dealing with "text" characters. Also note that you could reinterpret_cast<long*> if you wanted to -- reading through that pointer would then likely access 4 additional bytes (if your long is 64 bit) which are from other things in memory, or even not allocated at all which would cause a crash. So again, be careful with the casts.
